# data annotation implementation in wcf asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have the following in my Solution (it consists of 4 projects)

1. Infrastructure (Model class)
2. Repository
3. Service (WCF)
4. Web (Presentation)

**I used Service Reference Wizard  (Add Service Reference) to consume the service in my Web (Presentation)**

I have the following running in infrastructure takes care of the model classes:

**Infrastucture**

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace Infrastructure
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DataAnnotationsExtensions;

[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class COUNTRIES
{
public COUNTRIES()
{
    this.CITIES = new HashSet<CITIES>();
    this.LGA = new HashSet<LGA>();
    this.STATES = new HashSet<STATES>();
}

[DataMember]
public int COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }

// [DataMember(Name = "Country Code")]
[DataMember]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Country Code is required")]
[Display(Name = "Country Code")]
[StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {1} characters long. Plese check again!", MinimumLength = 2)]
//[Index(IsUnique = true)]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
public string COUNTRY_CODE { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Country Name is required")]
[Display(Name = "Country Name")]
//[Index(IsUnique = true)]
//[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Too long. Plese check again!")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {1} characters long. Plese check again!", MinimumLength = 2)]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
public string COUNTRY_NAME { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[Display(Name = "Action Status")]
public int ACTION_STATUS { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[Display(Name = "Date Created")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATED_DATE { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[Display(Name = "Created By")]
public Nullable<int> CREATED_BY { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[Display(Name = "Last Update Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_UPDATE_DATE { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[Display(Name = "Last Update By")]
public Nullable<int> LAST_UPDATE_BY { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[Display(Name = "Date Deleted")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DELETED_DATE { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[Display(Name = "Deleted By")]
public Nullable<int> DELETED_BY { get; set; }


[DataMember]
public virtual ICollection<CITIES> CITIES { internal get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual ICollection<LGA> LGA { internal get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual ICollection<STATES> STATES { internal get; set; }
 }
 }
```

**Then, for my Service: WCF**

```
namespace BPP.CCSP.Admin.Services.Services.Concrete
{

[ValidateDataAnnotationsBehavior]

public class CountriesService : ICountriesService
{
//public void DoWork()
//{
//}
 private readonly ICountriesManager _countriesManager;

 public CountriesService(ICountriesManager countriesManager)
 {
    _countriesManager = countriesManager;
 }

 public COUNTRIES GetCountry(Int32 countryID)
 {
    return _countriesManager.Country(countryID);
 }

public IEnumerable<COUNTRIES> GetCountries()
{
    return _countriesManager.Countries();
}

public void AddCountry(COUNTRIES countries)
{
    _countriesManager.AddCountry(countries);
}

public void RemoveCountry(int countryID)
{
    _countriesManager.Country(countryID);
}
}
}
```

> The issue I have is that the data annotation is not being implemented.

This is the flow:
**Infrastructure (model) => Repository => Service(WCF) => Web (Presentation)**

Please, how do I make data annotation and validation not being implemented in the presentation layer (view)

Comment: You should try to [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your chances of getting help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to implement data annotation then you should have models reference to your presentation, once you add ref into your presentation layer then you can validate model inside your controller and then call your WCF service.

Make model as shared entity with will shared across all Repository, Service(WCF), Presentation.

Hope this will help you